# Regex for numbers, commas and whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a RegEx that allow the strings that start with numbers separated by comma, finishes with a number (or withspaces after the number) and allow also whitespaces between the number and the comma.
E.g. `var str= '1 , 8,9,  88'` has to be accetpted while `var str2="1   2, 5"` has not to be accetped. I tried with `var regEx= "^[0-9\,\s]+$"`but doing like this it accepts the strings that end with a comma and the strings that have two numbers not separated by comma. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Example of string accepted:

```
str1= "1,2,3,4"
str2= "1 , 2,3,9"
str3= "  8 , 44, 3  , 11"
```

Example of string to be discarded:

```
str4="1, 2,"
str5=", 1,2,"
str6="1,2 3,4"
```

Comment: Can you give some more examples of valid and invalid inputs? Do you only accept multiple whitespaces if they are around a comma?

Comment: i think you've made a mistake in your example

Comment: question edited ;)

Comment: what if str="1", accepted or discarded?

Comment: str="1" is accepted @V-SHY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could account for the spaces before and after the comma using `\s` (or just match a space only because `\s` also matches a newline) to match a whitespace character and use a repeating pattern to match a comma and 1+ digits:

```
^\s*\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*\s*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*\d+` Match 0+ whitespace chars and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\s*,\s*\d+` Match 0+ whitespace chars, and comma, 0+ whitespace chars and 1+ digits
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\s*$` Match 1+ whitespace chars and assert end of string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JXvtf1/1)

Comment: One case is missing, with trailing space/s e.g `1  `

Comment: It works partially because if the string ends with a whitespace after the last number it does not work

Comment: Yes! @RehanHaider

Comment: If I test the regEx online it works but if I write in my code Validators.pattern("^\s*\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*\s*$") it does not work. What I am missing?

Comment: @GigiProve Did you try to double escape the backslash? `^\\s*\d+(?:\\s*,\\s*\\d+)*\\s*$`